# jquery check checkbox by id in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which the name of a user is passed in and the ID of the checkbox will be that name, I'm trying to get jquery to check it by the ID, but no luck. the ID field of the checkbox is called by each user name so it needs to find the correct checkbox called by the 'name' passed in and check it.

```
function send_new_message(name)
{
var html = new_message_form();
var div = $(html);

//Set user clicked to checked
//$("#dave").prop("checked", true);
$("#" + name).prop('checked', true);   

div.find('.send').click(function()
{
//Remove any error message
$("p.error").html('');

//Error check
var name = $("input.name").val();
var message = $("#message").val();

if(message==""){
$(".error").html('This filed is required!');
$("#message").focus();  
return false;  
}

//Send message to be processed
var post_data = name + "##@##" + message;
$.post(
'frames/process_messages.php',
{name: name, message: message},
function(result){
alert(result);
}
);      
//Close
//div.dialog('close');
});

div.dialog(
{
title:"Send New Message",
width: 450,
show: {
effect: "fold",
duration: 500
},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 500
},
close: function(){
$(this).dialog("destroy");
$(this).remove();       
}
});
}
```

HTML (PHP echo's)

```
<tr><td><input class=\'names\' id=\''.$users[$i]['name'].'\' type=\'checkbox\' name=\'names[]\' value=\''.$users[$i]['id'].'\' /></td><td>'.$users[$i]['name'].'</td></tr>
```

rendered

```
<tr><td><input class='names' id='dave' type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='3' /></td><td>dave</td></tr>
```

does not seem  to work :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Wrap `'+name+'` in double quotes and see if that works.

Comment: `document.getElementById(name).checked = true;`

Comment: um, why are you not just using `$("#"+name)`

Comment: You forgot the `);` at the end of your `div.find('.send').click(function()`

Comment: It's there before div.dialog(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it's the ID, you can do:

```
$("#" + name).prop('checked', true);
```

and use `prop()` when changing attributes that take boolean values.

Comment: I check the name is being passed with alert(name), and it is but its not checking the text box

Comment: Is that PHP variables for ID? Is this markup between `<?php ?>` tags? I suppose it would be better if you could post the rendered markup.

Comment: Ok, done that now, I can't see why your code should not work :S

Comment: If you instead run the line `$("#dave").prop("checked", true);` does it work?

Comment: I don't think so, im on chrome and look at its console using crl-shift-J. If thats what you mean

Comment: This is weird...your element is on the page, console shows no errors, the selector is perfect, is there anything else in that function besides setting the checkbox?

Comment: yes, there is, I will post the whole function. I tried it in a new html document without everything and it worked, so something is not making it work in the current document.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31002/discussion-between-user1977434-and-tymejv)

Answer (score 11):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change runtime properties like checked and disabled

```
$('#'+name).prop('checked', true);
```

You can read more about the difference in the documentation for [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get a handle on a specific checkbox with the following code:

```
var myCheckbox=$("input[name='checkbox_name']");
myCheckbox.change(function(){
     if(this.checked){
          alert('checked');
     } else {
          alert('unchecked');
     }
});
```